# intermittent ethernet connection - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Dell Optiplex 755

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Optiplex 755. The PC is connected via Ethernet, no WiFi. The Ethernet connection shows up as "Wired Connection 1" in network status on the top bar.

However, this Ethernet connection disconnects every few minutes, mostly without a warning. In network status, the connection shows up as still established. I have to click "Disconnect" and then again "Wired Connection 1" to get it going again. But after a few minutes, it disconnects again, without notification.

I'm pretty sure it's not a hardware problem, since I was running the same PC with the same Ethernet hardware under Windows 7 without any problems. For extra confirmation,I also tried another cable.

It would be great to get some input from you on that matter.

Here is the output from sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network               
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 19
  bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
  logical name: enp0s25
  version: 02
  serial: 00:21:9b:4f:e3:56
  size: 100Mbit/s
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=1.4-0 ip=192.168.0.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
  resources: irq:35 memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff memory:fe9db000-fe9dbfff ioport:ecc0(size=32
```

Comment: Does anything related to your network appear in `dmesg`?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and I'll take a look. Ping me at @heynnema.

Comment: thanks @heynnema, I just added the output of sudo lshw -C network to my original question

Comment: This is a different interface than what I was looking to give advice on. However, I do notice that you only got a 100mbit ethernet connection, and you should have a 1000mbit connection, so one of your cables is probably incorrect, or you don't have megabit routers/switches.

Comment: thanks @heynnema! it should be 1000T, but I'll check. That does not explain the intermittent connection though, is there anything else I could check? The same computer with the same network card, same cable and same router  worked fine with other operating systems.